# ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - expo build

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to upload my apps using Expo to app store connect. Unfortunately, it failed and return this message

> ERROR ITMS-90163: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. The bundle contains a key that is not included in the provisioning profile: 'com.apple.developer.icloud-services' in 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp'."

I already tried couple ways to build the apps by:

1. let expo handle the certificate
2. Manually generate the provisioning profile and certificate itself

Any thoughts to solve this problem?

notes: I already defined a unique bundle identifier name as well and already detected on bundle id in My App on appstore connect

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who finds this now. If you are having this problem in the expo managed workflow, you need to do 2 things.

First, in your apple developer account dashboard you must navigate to Certificates, Identfiers and Profiles.

In Identifiers, you must edit the identifier and check the box next to ICloud (or any other of the features listed there that you want, e.g. Associated Domains for Universal Links)

Second, you must build with a new provisioning profile using:

```
expo build:ios -t archive --clear-provisioning-profile
```

You may manually provide a new provisioning profile or let expo handle it. If you choose not to revoke the previous provisioning profile, you should choose to use a new one when asked.